# Get values in table A column using CSV from a column B in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like so:

```
Table Items
+--------------------+
| id | item          |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Table         |
+----+---------------+
| 2  | couch         |
+----+---------------+
| 3  | Bed           |
+----+---------------+
| 4  | Chair         |
+----+---------------+
| 5  | Desk          |
+----+---------------+

Table Acme
+--------------------+--------+
| id | items         | Client |
+----+---------------+--------+
| 1  | 1,3,5         | S45-56 |
+----+---------------+--------+
```

What I need is to use CSV from Acme table to select items in Items table

I tried using the following query but I only get the first of the tree values

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE id IN (SELECT items FROM Acme WHERE client ='S45-56')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to check if a value is in a comma separated list.

```
SELECT i.*
       FROM items i
            INNER JOIN acme a
                       ON find_in_set(i.id, a.items)
       WHERE a.client = 'S45-56';
```

But it's best to fix your schema and don't use comma separated lists but multiple rows in a table instead.

Comment: Love it, it worked like a charm.
Thank You sticky bit.

Comment: +1 for schema fix advice. SQL engines are way better when dealing with relations than having to work with some poorly represented data. In that case a third table would be preferable.